Crash when using enum with associated values
This is how I initialize my model container:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    init() {
        do {
            modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: MyModel.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
        }
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(modelContainer)

        }
    }
}

and this is the rest of code that can reproduce the issue:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

enum DayOfWeek: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday
}

enum FrequencyType: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case daily(interval: Int)
    case specificDaysOfWeek([DayOfWeek])
}

@Model
final class MyModel: Identifiable {

    init() {
        self.frequency = .daily(interval: 1)
    }

    @Attribute(.unique)
    private(set) var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    private(set) var frequency: FrequencyType

    func setFrequency(_ frequency: FrequencyType) {
        self.frequency = frequency
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    private let model = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Content View")
            .onAppear {
                modelContext.insert(model)
                model.setFrequency(.specificDaysOfWeek([.friday, .monday]))
            }
    }
}

what is happening is that when I do something like:
model.setFrequency(.specificDaysOfWeek([.friday, .monday]))

application crashes with this error:

CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
<NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x60000374c300> ,
[<Foundation.__NSSwiftData 0x600000c6e8b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _buffer. with
userInfo of {
NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = {length = 29, bytes = 0x5b7b2266 72696461 79223a7b 7d7d2c7b ... 6179223a 7b7d7d5d };
NSUnknownUserInfoKey = "_buffer"; }

I don't get where this _buffer comes from, nor why crash happens?
EDIT:
This is what I get if I enable Core Data debugging (level 3):


Encoding .specificDaysOfWeek([.friday, .monday]) gives {"specificDaysOfWeek":{"_0":[{"friday":{}},{"monday":{}}]}}. I'm guessing the _0 you see in the json is _buffer.

SwiftUI structs like App and View should not make objects like ModelContainer in their init or body. You need to move it to an action like onAppear or it's a memory leak and looks like a crash in your case. Alternatively use the convenience .modelContainer(for: MyModel.self) which makes the object at the right time for you.

@malhal If you try to use what you suggested, you will see that you will get error: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for MyModel. Thats why I initialized it that way, just to create minimal reproducible example. Thanks for hints though, however, the point in this question was the SwiftData crash, not the app architecture & best practices.

Since this happens at the Core Data/sql level you could turn on core data debug logging and see if that reveals anything interesting

@Timmy So, what do you suggest, some custom encoding for FrequencyType enum?

@JoakimDanielson I turned that on, but it wasn't helpful for me. I can post it here... Just a sec.

Unfortunately that log excerpt isn't relevant at all since it's for a different table.

@JoakimDanielson Its all I can see in console when I run this code :(

Then my guess is that this is an internal crash in Core Date before trying to persist the data. I will see if I can reproduce this myself.

After investigating and debugging this issue I have concluded that this happens when generating SQL related to the property and also that the encoding of the property is working as expected so I can only assume this is a bug/unsupported since there is no interference of custom code in the process.
A workaround for this could be to make the enum property into a computed property and than use a struct for a private property that gets persisted instead of the enum. This means having an extra type and some glue code but the public api would remain the same so when this issue is fixed in SwiftData then only the model would need to be migrated.
struct InternalFrequencyType: Codable {
    let interval: Int?
    let daysOfWeek: [DayOfWeek]?

    init(frequencyType: FrequencyType) {
        switch frequencyType {
        case .daily(let interval):
            self.interval = interval
            daysOfWeek = nil
        case .specificDaysOfWeek(let array):
            daysOfWeek = array
            interval = nil
        }
    }

    var toFrequencyType: FrequencyType {
        if let interval {
            return .daily(interval: interval)
        } else {
            //alternatively to '?? []' use forced unwrapping or throw an error 
            return .specificDaysOfWeek(daysOfWeek ?? [])
        }
    }
}

The changes to the model would then be
private var internalFrequencyType: InternalFrequencyType
var frequency: FrequencyType {
    get { internalFrequencyType.toFrequencyType }
    set { internalFrequencyType = .init(frequencyType: newValue) }
}

and in the init
internalFrequencyType = .init(frequencyType: .daily(interval: 1))


Thanks, it worked like this. And yeah, it seem like unsupported  thing at the moment of speaking...
